# Relationship between PDFs and derivatives

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a well-known formula in probability theory - and by the way I m looking for the name of this formula or theorem? (Because it would be nice to be able to refer to it by a name) - :

$f_Y(y) = f_X(x)|dx/dy|$

The main question is: how to intuitively interpret the role of the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$? Which by the way is harder to interpret given the kind of "inverse" notion $x$ with respect to $y$ instead of y with respect to x. Aslo y is a function of $x$ e.g. $y = g(x)$

I imagine it is some kind of variation in the output domain with respect to the input domain... but I can't formulate it well...

Reference to formula in [Wikipedia entry for pdf function under the section "scalar to scalar"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the definition

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y \leq y)=F_X(g^{-1}(y))$$

Derivating you get

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))\frac{dx}{dy}$$

That is your formula but the absolute value. This is due to the fact that this formula is the same also for $g$ decreasing.

P.S. this formula is known as "fundamental transformation Theorem "

Comment: Thanks,  so is it correct to say that : from the definition with the CDFs $F_Y(...)$, you integrate on both sides with respect to y to obtain the formula?

Comment: By the way thanks for the thm s name

Comment: However it does noy seem obvious to me how to integrate $F_X(g^{-1}(y)) $? It is a composite function and some composite functions do not have antiderivatives like $e^{x^2}$ for example.. How to proceed with $\int F_X(g^{-1}(y))  dy = ...$

Comment: @Machupicchu As tommik mentioned, he is differentiating $F_X(g^{-1}(y))$, not integrating.

Comment: Ohhh yes thanks! Sorry, i m a bit tired.. of course he is derivating both sides wrt y and I thst is required since to cancel the integral in the CDF  to obtain the pdf, one must of course differentiate. So I guess that the $dx/dy$ is the internal derivative of $F_X(g^{-1}(y))$ (chain rule of derivatives) and because $x=g^{-1}(y)$, all correct?

Comment: On thing that is misleading for me, (but maybe I should post a new question?) is that if the 2 density functions  $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are to be equal but have a different shape e.g.. one is a uniform  distribution and the other is not ,    (because that is what i m interested in, in the end), how can we "intuitively " understand that this leads to them having the same CDF i.e. same prob that Y $\leq$ y ... even if I see that this mathematically come out of the derivations but in a more "intuitive" sense?

Comment: (Maybe I m confused a bit because for discrete pmfs - unless i m mistaken this is not possible - or perhaps I m missing something fundamental)

Comment: @Machupicchu There is an important assumption that $g$ (the transformation from $X$ to $Y$) is increasing.

Comment: Yes I remember that there was a monotonicity assumption. But can you say in one sentence from what stating that $F_Y(y)=F_X(x)$ stems from  exactly?

Comment: To kind of "say it in english": This should mean that "the prob that Y (which is in fact built as Y=g(X) ) is lesser than a given $y$ should be the same as the prob that X is less than $ g^{-1}(y)$ because X and Y are linked by yhis transformation i.e.$ x= g^{-1}(y)$ ... So ...yes in fact  I think i get it now... do you agree (I know "it seems obvious  but when dealing with probabilities yhingss always gets a bit tricky)?